# How to join information in a multidimensional array having the value of a key as a base?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to organize a multidimensional array (just one) so that a child array is always as "children" of its parent, taking into account its id.

If there are duplicates, it should join (so that only one is left).

I've already tried mixing functions like array_search, array_key_exists, array_values, etc. but to no avail.

The array I have:

```
array 
          0 => 
            array 
              'id' => 111
              'name' => 'A' 
              'father' => 222
              'children' => 
                array 
                  'id' => 333
                  'name' => 'B' 
                  'father' => 111
                  'children' => null
          1 => 
            array 
              'id' => 111
              'name' => 'A'
              'father' => 222
              'children' => 
                array 
                  'id' => 444
                  'name' => 'C' 
                  'father' => 111
                  'children' => null
         2 => 
            array 
              'id' => 222
              'name' => 'D'
              'father' => 0
              'children' => null
```

The array I want:

```
array 
          0 => 
            array 
              'id' => 222
              'name' => 'D' 
              'father' => 0
              'children' => 
                array 
                  'id' => 111
                  'name' => 'A' 
                  'father' => 222
                  'children' => 
                       array 
                         'id' => 333
                         'name' => 'B' 
                         'father' => 111
                         'children' = null
                       array 
                         'id' => 444
                         'name' => 'C' 
                         'father' => 111
                         'children' => null
```

A recursive method seems to me the best way to approach the question, but I can not implement it.

How would you solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want that structure? It looks like a mess

Comment: *"I've already tried mixing functions like array_search, array_key_exists, array_values, etc. but to no avail."* – this is not representative of an attempt. Please share your code and ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I - sort of - understand what you're trying to do, but your array gets complicated very soon and searching it will be a nightmare. I suppose every person has a unique id, so why not use a onedimensional array, with the **id's as keys**. Like this:

```
[
111=>[
   name => A,
   father => 67,
   mother => 666,
   children => [333,444,555]
   ],
222=>[
   name => B,
   father => 111,
   mother => 767,
   children =>[923]
   ]
333=>[
   name => C,
   father = > 111,
   mother => 352,
   children = > ?
   ]
767=>[
   name => D,
   father => ?,
   mother => ?,
   children => [222]
   ]
]
```

Now in case you want to look something up, you only have to refer to the ID's.

children of A:

```
id_A=111
lookup children: $array[111][children] => 333, 444, 555
name_child = $array[333][name]
name_child = $array[444][name]
name_child = $array[555][name]
```

mother of B:

```
B_id = 222
lookup mother: $array[222][mother] => 767
mother_name = $array[767][name]
```

sibblings of C:

```
C_id = 333
lookup father: $array[333][father] => 111
lookup children: $array[111][children] => [333,444,555]
name_sibbling = $array[333][name]
name_sibbling = $array[444][name]
name_sibbling = $array[555][name]
```

grandparents on mothers side of B:

```
Person_id => Mother_id => Mother_Father_id == grandfather
Person_id => Mother_id => Mother_Mother_id == grandmother
```

Comment: The only problem is that the first array came from the db, this way it is necessary to change the query. But I understand what you are saying and I agree that this is the way to go. Thank you